# Customize \chaptermark for \mainmatter

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

Hey guys it's me again,

I tried to add `\leftmark` to my header, but I want to change it from `Chapter 1. Introduction` to `1 Introduction`. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
        \chapter{Introduction}
        \chapter{Blablabla}
\end{document}
```

I googled a lot a found `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}` and other variations and inserted it at different places of the preamble, but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something important again? Guess so, but I couldn't point it out.

Comment: What header do you want in the front matter?

Comment: I got multiple headers in the front matter, but I want the TOC and my thesis to have the same header - Display only "X Chaptername". So "Chapter" and the "." shall be removed.

Comment: Oh I just saw that I made a mistake. I wrote `\rigthmark` in my MWE, but said `\leftmark` in my explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\chaptermark` can be redefined the following way:

```
\makeatletter
\if@twoside
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 %
        \thechapter\ %
      \fi
      #1%
    }{}%
  }%
\else
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markright{%
      \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 %
        \if@mainmatter  
          \thechapter\ %
        \fi
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

It prints the headers:

```
CONTENTS
1 Introduction
2 Blablabla
```

The upper casing of `CONTENTS` can be removed by the redefinition of `\tableofcontents`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}{}{}
```

That removed `\MakeUppercase` from the definition of `\tableofcontents` (twice).

Comment: Hm that's kinda odd. I tried your solution an it works perfectly fine, but than I noticed that I used `\rightmark` instead of `\leftmark`. But isn't `\leftmark` the command for the chapters? When I use it in my actual document it displays nothing at all.

Comment: @Chris.V: You are using document class option `oneside` with chapter titles in the header only. For completeness I have added the version for class option `twoside`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using `oneside` because I'm only allowed to print it onesided. Your solution worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.