# Remove all-caps ToC, LoF, ... in header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

yesterday I tried to remove the all-caps of my ToC, LoF, ... in my documents header and think I encountered a problem/bug. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in, headheight = 14.5pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[L]{\itshape \leftmark}
 \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
  \renewcommand{\tocetcmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
 \mainmatter
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I'm using `tocbibind` to include my LoF and LoT in the ToC. My problem is, if I use `\renewcommand{\tocetcmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}` it only displays my LoF and LoT normalsized in my header. But the documentation for `tocbibind` says that this command is for ToC, LoF, ... . Why is my ToC still all-caps? Is it some kind of bug or am I overlooking something?

In one of my previous questions ([Customize \chaptermark for \mainmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120603/customize-chaptermark-for-mainmatter)) Heiko Oberdiek already gave me a solution for the ToC problem in advance:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\contentsname}{}{}
```

It works really fine, but why doesn't the first method does it job properly? Or is there even a smarter way to remove all the all-caps at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `tocbibind` only overwrites default definitions of `listof<...>` which you have specified. You passed the option `nototoc` and so there is no redefinition of the default `\tableofcontents`. So you have to use the provided patch of Heiko.