# Only number and name of chapter wanted in header

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I have the problem, that in my header "chapter" is mentioned, but I only want the chapter number and name to appear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\Huge \bf \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge \bf} %This is here, so that at each chapter start, I only get "chapter number + chapter name"
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{dsfjdj}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

The right mark works the way I want it to, but the left mark doesn't, since it also lists the word "chapter" explicitly. How can I avoid it?

Comment: can you please make your code complete?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120603/customize-chaptermark-for-mainmatter?s=1|1.9537 for example.

Comment: You may like to take a look at [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/4918) :-)

Comment: @John Kormylo Thanks that worked. Now I only see chapter number and chapter title in the header. But now, the thing is: it is not written in the same style, as it is when I use leftmark. How could I change the code that was posted there, to make it look like it was written with leftmark?

Comment: Book class uses \MakeUppercase{...} to create the chapter head.

Answer (score 1):

Since  you use `titlesec`, I suggest you use `titleps`, which is easier to use than `fancyhdr`, in my opinion. It allows to define a new page style without using marks with a simple syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge \bfseries}{\Huge \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} %This is here, so that at each chapter start, I only get "chapter number + chapter name"

\newpagestyle{myps}{%
\sethead[\small\scshape\thechapter. ~\titlecap{\chaptertitle}][][]{}{}{\small\thesection.~\itshape\sectiontitle}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{myps}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A first chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Some section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work, since I use \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} in between and those two seem to interfere with each other.

Comment: Yes, don't load both `fancyhdr` and `titleps`If you want a headrule (there's none by default, contrary to fancyhdr), you just have to mention `\headrule` in the description of the page style. Thickness (0.4pt by default), is changed with, say, `\setheadrule{0.8pt}`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the link posted by @John Kormylo and modified it a bit. This way, I get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\Huge \bf \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge \bf} %This is here, so that at each chapter start, I only get "chapter number + chapter name"
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{
        \uppercase{\thechapter \, #1}
    }{}%
  }%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{%
        \uppercase{\thesection \, #1}
    }{}%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{dsfjdj}
\newpage

\end{document}
```